# How to override JS with my custom theme?

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides

I am trying to overwrite the `module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js` file,

I have added the file to `app/design/frontend/Magento/theme_fresh/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`,

I flushed the **cache**, **static files** etc but it isn't loading the file I copied, if I make changes to the core file (I only did it to make sure it is working) and the override file then only the change to the core file will show.

Comment: Just remove your browser cache and check.

Answer (score 1):

If your theme is enabled, your path is right so try to run these commands on your installation root to clean all old configuration:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ && 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ; 
php -r "opcache_reset();" 
mage cache:flush & 
mage indexer:reindex & 
mage setup:upgrade && 
mage setup:static-content:deploy && 
mage setup:db-data:upgrade && 
mage dev:source-theme:deploy && 
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```